# Can I make text in xterm looks and feels like gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm

[image]

The picture on top you can see my xterm, the picture under is the gnome-terminal.

Ok This is what I want to get:

I use the same font in both but looks different:

```
Xterm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono Bold:size=11:antialias=true
```

how can I fix this?

//EDIT

add more info of my xterm:

```
ldd `which xterm` | grep -E '(freetype|fontconfig)'
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f07bcbcc000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f07bb2f3000)
```

my `.Xdefaults`

```
!XTerm*background: #2D2D2D
XTerm*background: #FFFFDD
!XTerm*foreground: #D2D2D2
XTerm*scrollBar:  off
XTerm*vt100*geometry:   88x24
Xterm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono Bold:size=11
XTerm*renderFont: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's just a typo. Try changing

```
Xterm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono Bold:size=11
```

to

```
XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono Bold:size=11
```

(`XTerm` rather than `Xterm`)

Answer (score 7):

The above is a bitmap font (looks very much like `-misc-fixed-*-r-semicondensed`). What you need is to enable TrueType fonts in XTerm. Provided your XTerm has been compiled with TrueType support, you want to set the `xterm*renderFont` property to `true` in your `~/.Xdefaults` (or wherever you may have it).

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
```

Alternatively you can do it in the XTerm "VT Fonts" menu which you open with <kbd>Ctrl + Right Mouse Button</kbd>, yet that is only per window setting of course.

To make sure `xterm` is compiled with TrueType support:

```
$ ldd `which xterm` | grep -E '(freetype|fontconfig)'
```

you should get something like:

```
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6
```

Comment: added that but does not look that any changes has made. I edited `vi ~/.Xdefaults` and then added `XTerm*renderFont: true` save the changes and do `xrdb .Xdefaults` with no luck. Acctually the color of the font changes a little like the gome's. but the font is not the same as the one in gnome-terminal.

Comment: I think it should be `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults`.

Comment: OK actually this does not solve it. I want to do something that actually change the shape of the font like `gnome-terminal`. Maybe it can't be done

Comment: Let's focus on what it does so that we can move further. Did you see **any** change whatsoever?

Comment: actually my xterm still looks like the picture I show in the question.

Comment: Can you post **all** your (user) XTerm configuration? But first check, that check xterm has TT support (see my updated answer).

Comment: added the info take a look =)

Comment: @peterph: I think you missed something. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson well spotted! I have to partly blame the monospace font, that SE is forcing... ;/